# Does chinaware need Tevilat keilim

Tags: halacha, gentiles, yoreh-deah, tevilas-keilim-dipping, utensil

According to Halacha, does chinaware need tevilat keilim when it is bought by a Jew from a gentile or no? Is this question  a machloket  amongst the different poskim?

Comment: Please Google before asking? A lot of these questions can readily be found elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from [Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tevilat_Keilim#Basics)

> Which Vessels require Tevilah?
>
> 1. While the immersion of metal utensils is required by Torah law, glass utensils must be immersed only by rabbinic enactment. Glass was
>    incorporated into the mitzva of tevilat keilim because glass and metal
>    share a common characteristic - they are both materials which can be
>    melted and reconstructed when needed. [28]
> 2. Metal, glass, crystal, pyrex, and duralux require Tevilah. However, plastic, nylon, earthenware, and vessels covered in earthenware do not
>    require Tevilah. [29]
> 3. Some say that porcelain requires Tevilah.[30] Some say it does not need tevila.[31] According to Sepharadim, porcelain does not require
>    tevila. [32]
> 4. Plastic or wood cutting boards do not need Tevilah, but those who are strict and do Tevilah for it will be blessed.[33]
> 5. Earthenware dishes or fine china that have a glass glaze must have tevilat keilim.[34]
> 6. Anything used to improve the food that is ready to eat needs tevila include a metal noodle strainer.[35] However, a utensil that only
>    prepares ingredients that are not edible after that stage of the
>    cooking require tevila without a bracha, such as a metal flour
>    sifter.[36]
> 7. Similarly, jars, bottles, or metal containers which are used only to store food and not used for food preparation or consumption should
>    be immersed without a blessing. Utensils which are only used
>    indirectly with food, such as bottle or can openers, and the like, do
>    not require immersion.[37]
> 8. Common custom is not to require the immersion of plastic utensils[38] even though some authorities argue that the similarities
>    between glass and plastic would require it. [39]
> 9. Utensils which one is certain that they contain no glass or metal components need not be immersed. [40]
> 10. Corelle dishes are halachically similar to glass dishes and should be immersed. According to most poskim they are immersed with a bracha.
>     [41]
> 11. One should immerse the kos shel eliyahu used for the seder night without a beracha.[42]
> 12. Regarding a seder plate if the food directly touches the seder plate it requires tevila and if not it doesn't.[43]
> 13. Tongs used to do tevilat kelim don't themselves need tevilat kelim.[44]
> 14. A mixer should have tevila without a bracha since it is usually used to mix foods which aren't ready to eat immediately.[45]
> 15. A pocketknife requires tevilah. [46]

It seems to me that chinaware is dealt with under item 5 and does need tevila because of the glaze.

Porcelain (= vitrified pottery with a white, fine-grained body that is usually translucent) is the subject of machlokes - item 3; earthenware -item 2, which is porous, opaque, and coarser than porcelain does not need tevila.